# Animate transition on multiple objects with a single animation in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I use KnockoutJS 2.1 for a news application I'm currently working on. I've created a 4 by 2 grid, presenting 8 news articles at a time (see image below).

[image: 4 by 2 grid of news items]

I've added paging to this grid, so when you click on the next-button, 8 new news-articles are presented. This works perfectly fine! However, what I would like is to **add an animation to the transition**, so when you click Next, **8 new articles slide in from the right hand side, pushing the previous 8 articles out of the screen to the left.** Something like this:

[image: Animated transition]

I've seen [the example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html) on the Knockout website, using `afterAdd` and `beforeRemove` to apply animated transitions using jQuery. The problem with this approach is that the animation is applied to each individual news article. **I need to animate all articles at the same time, with a single animation.**

The idea I have, is that I would use a wrapper-element around all 8 news articles, with `overflow: hidden`. I could then add 8 new articles to the right of the current articles, the new articles would still be out of sight due to the hidden overflow. I could then slide all 16 articles to the left, so that the new articles are visible instead, and the old articles are out of sight to the left. I could then remove the 8 old articles from the DOM.

I'm not sure if that is even possible with Knockout, or if there might be a better approach to take.

**How would you animate the transition of 8 articles being added to the DOM and 8 articles being removed from the DOM, through a single animation?**

Comment: That sounds perfectly reasonable. Just be careful when you remove the previous elements from the DOM, as that will change the scroll offset.

Answer (score 1):

Could your Knockout template add them in groups of 8 to an overall container, then you animate the container left or right the width of a group? Something like this:

```
<div class="newsCarousel">

  <div class="newsGroup">
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    ...
    <h2>Title 8</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="newsGroup">
    <h2>Title 9</h2>
    <h2>Title 10</h2>
    <h2>Title 11</h2>
    ...
    <h2>Title 16</h2>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That would probably be a solution. I don't remember how we finally solved this. I believe the transition effect was altered so that we used fade out/in effect instead. Thanks for you suggestion though!